# Counting overlaps in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, overlapping-features, arcgis-10.4

How can I count/find overlaps in ArcMap 10.4 but between area and line features (for example buildings and roads? Using topology I can find overlaps only between line-line or area-area feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try Spatial Join, it will provide a Join_Count.